# Regex to match URL not working

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I have the following function that loops through the browsers history (using the chrome API) and extracts any google search queries. I tested the regex on various websites and it works, but the doesn't seem to work in the JS function I created (doesn't log any URL's):

```
function getHistory(){
          var regex = '^https?:\/\/[^/]+\.google\.[a-z.]+\/((search[?#])|(webhp[?#])|([?#])).*q=';
          chrome.history.search({text:regex, maxResults:11}, function(data) {
              data.forEach(function(page) {
                  var url = page.url;
                  console.log(url);
          });
       });
    }
```

Comment: Double backslashes. `var regex = '^https?://[^/]+\\.google\\.[a-z.]+/(search[?#]|webhp[?#]|[?#]).*q=';`

Comment: This regex will match domains with google in them somewhere, aka `http://a.b.google.spamware.biz/search???????q=`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-search)
it doesn't look as though `chrome.history.search()` takes a regex, instead it takes a text search query, so its not suprising that it isn't finding any URLs that look like the literal regex.

While maybe not as efficient you could leave the text blank or use "google.com", then perform the regex filtering on the results.

Comment: exactly the way you are using it here, could you provide a working example?